# Why the electric field of a charged sphere in a conductor only depends on the charge of the sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, charge

Suppose we have a sphere, with a radius **a** and a total charge **$Q_{0}$**, immersed in a conductor, with a conductivity **$\sigma$** and a permittivity $\epsilon$ .The sphere releases a current density: $$ j= \sigma E$$
So, utilizing Maxwell's first law for an imaginary sphere of radius **r**, we can find the electric field: $$E = \frac{Q(t)}{4\pi\epsilon r^2} $$
And so the differential equation: $$ \frac{dQ(t)}{dt} = -\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}Q(t)$$
This, though, only takes into consideration the current charge of the *sphere* of radius **a**, without considering the *charge inside* the radius **r** caused by **j** flowing inside.
Why doesn't the density current influence the electric field even if it is *inside* the radius **r**? Is it simply *neglected* because small in comparison to the total electric field?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there's a current in a material doesn't imply there must be a charge imbalance in that material.

For example, in a copper wire, even when there are mobile electrons carrying a current, there are also protons with positive charge present. They don't contribute to current because they are not mobile, but fixed in place.

It is possible to produce a charge imbalance in a conductctive material (for example on a plate of a capacitor) but the mere fact of current present doesn't tell you that there is one.